# Best way to specify a dependency in Pyinstaller to a cli program called using subprocess

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Suppose I have a command line program written in Python 2.7. The command line utility calls a function which executes another command line program. The command is executed like this:

```
import subprocess
def exec_command(*args):
    process = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    return output, error
```

I would like to package the program using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). I've followed the instructions for adding a binary dependency and run pyinstaller like this:

```
pyinstaller cli.py --name <new_name> --add-binary <path_to_exec>:.
```

This works when I package the program as a folder and I can then call the executable in my packaged program by simple passing a list like this:

```
exec_command('<path_to_exec>',arg1,arg2)
```

However this does not work if I package the program as a file. If I do so I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Failed to execute script cli
```

So my question is, how can I call this script in my command line tool when packaged as a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile) which details how to access the temporary folder created by pyinstaller when it is bundled as a single file application. The function also works for the case where you have a folder packaged application.